# What is the type of block of the abbreviated IPv6 address?

Tags: networking, routes

What is the type of block of the abbreviated IPv6 address
4001:A100:FC1::AE12:5329:FBCA?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but the address you give is in a reserved range that is not allowed to be used at this time. Also,, according to _[RFC 5952, A Recommendation for IPv6 Address Text Representation](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952)_, you must convert the uppercase letters to lower case (instead of `4001:A100:FC1::AE12:5329:FBCA`, use `4001:a100:fc1::ae12:5329:fbca`): "_The characters "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", and "f" in an IPv6 address MUST be represented in lowercase."_